# Skipping disk check with diskutil resize?

Tags: disk-utility, partition

When running the `diskutil resize` command, is it possible to skip the disk verification step?

While I realise this ordinarily a good idea to run, I'm currently struggling against an apparently inaccurate minimum size being reported by the `limits` option, which is forcing me to run the command multiple times till I can find the actual minimum size that I can resize to, but this is taking forever as I'm forced to wait for a 10-15 minute disk check every time.

So what I'd like to know for future reference is; is there a way to tell `diskutil` to skip the disk verification when resizing, or to instead use a faster alternative (e.g- the `-p` flag of `fsck_hfs`)?

Comment: Why are you checking the limits? Is this to determine the maximum or minimum? What type of filesystem are you checking?

Comment: @DavidAnderson: I'm unsure of the relevance as the limits issue isn't what I want to solve, I just need to know if/how I can skip the volume verification. But if it helps it's an HFS+ partition and I was using limits to try to find the minimum I could shrink it to (so I could round up to something that should be a safe resize value).

Comment: If you were trying for a maximum, then you specify either a `0` or `R` depending on which `diskutil` resize command you are using. Most users ask about maximizing, but you are asking for the opposite. Sorry, for that, I can not help.